# Is the characteristic of ring invariant under homomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I'm completing my notes on the characteristic of a ring and I find these question:

> Under which conditions, can we guarantee that two rings $A,B$ are not
>   homomorphic given their characteristics?

So I wonder, is the characteristic invariant under homormorphism?

Comment: Consider the homomorphism $\Bbb Z_6\to \Bbb Z_6/(3)\cong \Bbb Z_3$. So characteristic is not invariant.

Comment: There is a statement along the lines of, "the characteristic of $A$ divides the characteristic of $B$", or perhaps the other way around.

Comment: Dear @Arthur Please consider adding that as a solution. It appears to be a completely solution to the question asked (the last sentence.) Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic is not invariant, consider $\Bbb Z_6\to \Bbb Z_6/(3)\cong \Bbb Z_3$, which is a homomorphism form a ring with characteristic $6$ to a ring with characteristic $3$.

However, that doesn't mean all hope is lost for the more general question: Let $f:A\to B$ be a homomorphism. By the definition of homomorphism, we must have
$$
0 = f(0) = f(1_A\cdot \operatorname{char} A) = 1_B\cdot \operatorname{char} A
$$
so we must have $\operatorname{char}B \mid \operatorname{char} A$ (note that this argument and especially the result also applies if either characteristic is $0$). So if the characteristic of $B$ does *not* divide the characteristic of $A$, then there is no homomorphism $A\to B$.